# Adding a UIImageView to a UIScrollView programmatically zooms the image

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I am building a User Profile page inside a `UICollectionReusableView` and atop the reusable view is a `UIScrollView` with user images. The `scrollview` is programmed (working correctly) to scroll horizontally between the users images. The problem is that the first image I add to the `scrollview` (the cover image) becomes zoomed in.

The code below shows my programatic implementation :

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: COLLECTION_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR)!
    view.isScrollEnabled = true
    view.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.isPagingEnabled = true
    return view
}()

private var coverImage: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    return view
}()
```

**Adding to the ReusableView**

```
private func setupView() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // ScrollView delegate
    scrollView.delegate = self
    
    // Scroll View Init
    addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 350)
    
    // Cover Image init
    scrollView.addSubview(coverImage)
    coverImage.frame = scrollView.frame
}
```

**What I Have Tried**

1. Changing the `ZoomScale`, `ZoomMin`, `ZoomMax` of the `ScrollView`.
2. Setting the `contentSize` of the `scrollView` after adding the `ImageView`.
3. Playing with the `contentMode` of the `ImageView` and the `ScrollView` (.`scaleAspectFit` etc.)
4. Adding the `ImageView` as a sub-view of the `ScrollView` after setting the ImageView's image
5. Calling `setupView()` in all Init methods and just one Init method at a time
6. Changing the `CGRect` of the `ImageView` and playing around with multiple ways of anchoring it to the view

   I have only seen noticeable changes from point 4 and 6 but none of which have been improvements. I have also looked at the other answer on this site that has a similar problem in `Objc`, however none of the solutions work.

Thanks in advance to whoever can help, when I was using storyboards this problem didn't occur.

Comment: How particularly it's zoomed? Since you tried scaleAspectFit for UIImageView.